# Can Mindless Assault be flipped for 4 power?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-vendetta

Mindless Assault reads:

> You may choose to flip 1 or more of your Deployed cards at this Location face down: each of your face down Deployed cards at this Location has 4 Power.

Can you flip Mindless Assault itself to give it 4 Power (up from 3)? I'd assume not since then all you'd be left with is a flipped-down card which by itself has a Power of 0. But one player argued that the effect already happened during the "Preparation" phase and thus "*each of your face down Deployed cards at this Location has 4 Power.*" is still in effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use *Mindless Assault*'s effect to flip itself face down, it's effect will no longer be active while face down, resulting in none of the face down cards counting for total Power value.

This is set out in the rulebook, and clarified by Horrible Guild team members on [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2891238/article/40360264#40360264) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/horribleguild/status/1243469938318245889):

> A2: how many you want. Keep in mind though that **the effect of face down cards is not active**, so you should keep those whose effect you need, and if you flip Shadow Strike, you lose its bonus (so don't flip it ).